# Android - Remove permission programmatically

Tags: java, android, permissions, adb

in the last days I try to make a simple Android app that can run adb command , more specific this command `pm revoke com.example.app android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE`.
I try to run this from pc and say me that I can't because this permission isn't changeable.
With root is possible? or there are other method to block the internet connection to one app?

Comment: I think what you need is a firewall. Google for "android firewall".

Comment: I search it , and I search also for open source firewall but is too complicated , some of firewall use ndk with C